# Predicting binary classification

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have been self-learning machine learning lately, and I am now trying to solve a `binary classification problem` (i.e: one label which can either be `true` or `false`). I was representing this as a single column which can be `1` or `0` (`true` or `false`).

Nonetheless, I was researching and read about how categorical variables can reduce the effectiveness of an algorithm, and how one should `one-hot encode` them or translate into a `dummy` variable thus ending with 2 labels (`variable_true`, `variable_false`).

Which is the correct way to go about this? Should one predict a single variable with two possible values or 2 simultaneous variables with a fixed unique value?

As an example, let's say we want to predict whether a person is a `male` or `female`:

Should we have a single label `Gender` and predict `1` or `0` for that variable, or `Gender_Male` and `Gender_Female`?

Comment: Hi! I'd consider https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for this (not a coding question). In a nutshell, one-hot encoding would apply to your model _features_ (those that you base your prediction on), not on the predicted label. Also, `Gender_Male` = `Gender` = 1 - `Gender_Female`, so it'd be redundant to keep more than one of them, as they are all equivalent (carry the very same information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's basically the same, when talking about binary classification, you can think of a final layer for each model that adapt the output to other model

e.g if the model output 0 or 1 than the final layer will translate it to vector like [1,0] or [0,1] and vise-versa by a threshold criteria, usually is >= 0.5

a nice byproduct of 2 nodes in the final layer is the confidence level of the model in it's predictions [0.80, 0.20] and [0.55, 0.45] will both yield [1,0] classification but the first prediction has more confidence

this can be also extrapolate from 1 node output by the distance of the output from the fringes 1 and 0 so 0.1 will be considered with more confidence than 0.3 as a 0 prediction